# Is Node Js a good fit for ReactNative apps?

Tags: react-native

I am making an app which is made using ReactNative, as ReactNative works with Node.js. So I was thinking of using Node.js as backend for apis. So is node.js a good fit for this structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React Native is backend agnostic, you should use whatever you are most comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course because Node.js is a platform built on Chrome's JavaScript runtime. reactnative also use javascript